# Proper way to create button in JQM

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

What is the proper way to create a button? The first way does not work...

```
<div class="buttonContainer">
   <button type="submit" onclick="moSucess()" >Sign In</button>
</div>
<a id="sincData" href="#sincPage" data-role="button" onclick="moSucess()">Submeter</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create a styled JQM button using an `a` tag, check out the [documentation here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/buttons/index.html) for this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/Z2saQ/).

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a>
```